# Higher homotopy groups of slice disk complement

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K \subseteq{\mathbb{S}}^3=∂\mathbb{D}^4$ be a non-trivial slice knot, i.e. $K$ bounds a slice disk $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{D}^4$. Let $N(\Delta)$ be a regular neighborhood of $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{D}^4$.

> What is known about $\pi_i(\mathbb{D}^4-N(\Delta))$, for $i\geq2$?

For what it's worth, $\pi_1(\mathbb{D}^4-N(\Delta))$ is known to be normally generated by the meridian of $K$. The knot complement $\mathbb{S}^3 - K$ and $∂(\mathbb{D}^4-N(\Delta))=M_K$ (the zero-framed surgery on the knot $K$) are both known to be aspherical.

Comment: I don't think the non-triviality of $K$ has much impact on your question.  For example, connect-sum any slice disc with a $2$-knot such as a Cappell-Shaneson knot.  

Comment: Ah, I wanted $K$ to be non-trivial since I believe that $\mathbb{S}^3-K$ is aspherical only for non-trivial knots.

Comment: You can also do a boundary connect-sum of two slice discs, that would give the connect sum of the two slice knots on the boundary. 

Comment: @Arunima Ray: If $K$ is trivial, its complement is an open solid torus, which is aspherical.

Comment: oops, my bad, I meant the the zero surgery on the knot $M_K$ is not aspherical for a trivial knot - if I've thought this through correctly, the zero surgery on the trivial knot is $\mathbb{S}^2x\mathbb{S}^1$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The homotopy groups can be pretty big things.  For example, your $D^4 - N(\Delta)$ class of spaces contains the class of all $2$-knot complements -- simply remove a 4-ball neighbourhood of $S^4$ that intersects the $2$-knot in an unknotted disc.

$2$-knot complements have fairly complicated homotopy groups.  For example, Cappell-Shaneson knot complements fiber over $S^1$ with fiber a once-punctured $(S^1)^3$.  The universal cover of this space is $\mathbb R \times (\mathbb R^3 - \mathbb Z^3)$, so by the Hilton-Milnor theorem, rationally the homotopy groups are a free lie algebra with countably-infinite many generators (up to the action of $\pi_1$ there's just one generator, though).

Off the top of my head I don't know if slice disc groups are any more general than knot groups, they're probably not very far from each other.  I think Kawauchi may not cover this but the references in his survey book should mention something.

Answer (score 10):

To add to Ryan's answer,

$2$--knots usually don't have aspherical complements, see [Dyer & Vasquez, The sphericity of higher dimensional knots, Canad. J. Math. 25(1973), 1132-1136](http://math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1973-121-5). This suggests a complicated answer for slice disks in general.

On the other hand, if the disk is ribbon, then the complement is aspherical, see [Asano, Marumoto, and Yanagawa,  T, Ribbon knots and ribbon disks, Osaka J. Math.
18 (1981), 161-174](http://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/metadb/up/LIBOJMK01/ojm18_01_12.pdf)

Comment: I've been thinking about this problem a bit more recently and learned that there are some issues with the second reference. See: On the asphericity of ribbon disc complements http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1985-289-01/S0002-9947-1985-0779064-8/home.html and Some remarks on a problem of JHC Whitehead https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(83)90038-1, both by James Howie. The asphericity of ribbon disc complements appears to be open and is related to the Whitehead conjecture.

Comment: Oh wow interesting.